# javascript Bind's function parameter explain

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi to all I'm beginner in javascript 
could somebody explain this code for me

```
a(this).bind("rfuSelect", { action: settings.onSelect }, function (j, h, i) {
  if (j.data.action(j, h, i) !== false) {
    var k = Math.round(i.size / 1024 * 100) * 0.01;
    alert(k.toString())
    var l = "KB";
  }
});
```

I need to know about the function parameters and the if Condition

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind explains the `bind` call and the parameters passed. First hit on a google search

Comment: This doesn't look like a typical use for JavaScript's `.bind()` method. Looks like it could be jQuery with a custom event, and event data bound.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: It's actually jQuery's `.bind()`.  http://api.jquery.com/bind/  Or so I assume.

Comment: what is `a`? Without that, we can't move much further.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I'm assuming `a` is `jQuery`.

Comment: If you're a beginner, I'd strongly suggest not digging through obfuscated code in search of knowledge.

Comment: @user2736012: This isn't *that* obfuscated, I've seen worse.  This is fairly readable-ish.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Sure, we were able to determine what it was. I'm saying that for a beginner, there are better ways to learn.

Comment: @user2736012: Obviously :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding events in jQuery, you can attach an object to the event.  Check the docs: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

The 1st parameter is the event type, in this case a custom event (`onrfuSelect`).

The 2nd (optional) parameter is a data object.  This object is available (as you can see) from [`event.data`](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/).

The 3rd parameter is the callback.  It's passed the [`Event`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object as its first parameter.  The other params are passed from jQuery's `.trigger` (this event can only be triggered manually, as it's not a DOM event).

`settings.onSelect` is a function, so `data.action` is a function.  The `if` statement calls that function with the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this is the JavaScript bind, not the jquery bind.  If this is jquery, you can ignore and go with another answer.

The first parameter is the `this` argument and the remaining parameters are arguments that are prepended to the argument call.

In your example above, the `this` object in the called function becomes `{ action: settings.onSelect }` and the first parameter to the function is the anonymous function expression you are passing in.

For more information, [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: From the parameters sent, this doesn't look like `Function.bind`.

Comment: Tanks for your explain in the example i use for file size where i take value

Comment: This is almost certainly not the native `.bind()`. The patter is reflective of jQuery usage, and would be odd for the native method.

Comment: I agree.  My answer might be technically correct, but most likely not the one you are looking for. Most likely @RocketHazmat has the information you want.